# Very slow MongoDB queries while using IXSCAN as a winning plan for queries

Tags: mongodb, indexing, journal

I have DB with about 30M records in a collection with about 100GB collection size (total documents and indexes).

I have a compound index that filters data based on user_id and some other fields like: `is_active`, `is_logged_in`, etc.

With `MongoDB Compass` I see slow queries of about 10s, 20s or even 40 seconds! I ran the exact same query and result is fetched less than 500ms (though it may get cached on second try).

When I get that ongoing `op` stat, I see the following lock status:

```
 "lockStats": {
         "Global": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 574
             }
         },
         "MMAPV1Journal": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 295
             },
             "acquireWaitCount": {
                 "r": 2
             },
             "timeAcquiringMicros": {
                 "r": 15494
             }
         },
 }
```

`acquireCount`: Number of times the operation acquired the lock in the specified mode is so high compared to the fast query (on another collection) that has the below status:

```
"lockStats": {
         "Global": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 2
             }
         },
         "MMAPV1Journal": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 1
             }
         },
         "Database": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 1
             }
         },
         "Collection": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "R": 1
             }
         }
     }
```

When operations are slow, and a user that has many records take so long it has domino effect on all the other operations after a few seconds.

When I explain the query on the large collection I can see the result that it has used an index:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "cuda.call_history",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "$or" : [ 
                        {
                            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "$nor" : [ 
                                {
                                    "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                        "$exists" : true
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "is_removed" : {
                        "$eq" : false
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "user_id" : {
                        "$eq" : "00000000000040008000000000002a5d"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "trk.0.direction" : {
                        "$eq" : "ingress"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "trk.0.type" : {
                        "$eq" : "fax"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : {
                        "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : {
                        "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "trk.0.data.status" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            "p_received", 
                            "success"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "$or" : [ 
                            {
                                "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                    "$eq" : false
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "$nor" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                            "$exists" : true
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "trk.0.type" : {
                            "$eq" : "fax"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "user_id" : 1,
                    "trk.0.direction" : 1,
                    "is_read" : 1,
                    "trk.0.data.status" : 1,
                    "is_removed" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "user_id_direction_is_read_status_is_removed",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user_id" : [ 
                        "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.direction" : [ 
                        "[\"ingress\", \"ingress\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_read" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.data.status" : [ 
                        "[\"p_received\", \"p_received\"]", 
                        "[\"success\", \"success\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_removed" : [ 
                        "[false, false]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ 
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "$or" : [ 
                                {
                                    "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                        "$eq" : false
                                    }
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "$nor" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                                "$exists" : true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "is_removed" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.direction" : {
                                "$eq" : "ingress"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.type" : {
                                "$eq" : "fax"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.data.status" : {
                                "$in" : [ 
                                    "p_received", 
                                    "success"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "user_id" : 1,
                        "date" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "user_id_date",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "user_id" : [ 
                            "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                        ],
                        "date" : [ 
                            "(\"2018-01-09 10:36:31\", \"1970-01-01 00:00:00\")"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "$or" : [ 
                                {
                                    "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                        "$eq" : false
                                    }
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "$nor" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                                "$exists" : true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "is_removed" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.direction" : {
                                "$eq" : "ingress"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.type" : {
                                "$eq" : "fax"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "date" : {
                                "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "date" : {
                                "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.data.status" : {
                                "$in" : [ 
                                    "p_received", 
                                    "success"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "user_id" : 1,
                        "to" : 1,
                        "from" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "user_id_to_from",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "user_id" : [ 
                            "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                        ],
                        "to" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ],
                        "from" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 4682,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 2072,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 4688,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 4682,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "$or" : [ 
                            {
                                "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                    "$eq" : false
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "$nor" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                            "$exists" : true
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "trk.0.type" : {
                            "$eq" : "fax"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 4682,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 710,
            "works" : 4897,
            "advanced" : 4682,
            "needTime" : 5,
            "needYield" : 209,
            "saveState" : 234,
            "restoreState" : 234,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 1,
            "docsExamined" : 4682,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 4682,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 305,
                "works" : 4688,
                "advanced" : 4682,
                "needTime" : 5,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 234,
                "restoreState" : 234,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "user_id" : 1,
                    "trk.0.direction" : 1,
                    "is_read" : 1,
                    "trk.0.data.status" : 1,
                    "is_removed" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "user_id_direction_is_read_status_is_removed",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user_id" : [ 
                        "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.direction" : [ 
                        "[\"ingress\", \"ingress\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_read" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.data.status" : [ 
                        "[\"p_received\", \"p_received\"]", 
                        "[\"success\", \"success\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_removed" : [ 
                        "[false, false]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 4688,
                "seeks" : 6,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : “hs1.mydomain.com”,
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.4.10",
        "gitVersion" : "078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

`keysExamined` is just 4,688! It is not much compared to the total data of the collection which is 30M documents. When Mongo gets slow when it has domino effect, CPU usage and Memory is not high. Mongo just uses 40% of the memory. Disk partition is `Ext4` if that helps.

Another example of a very slow query in full details:

```
{
    "desc": "conn199276",
    "threadId": "140070259820288",
    "connectionId": 199276,
    "client": "client_server_ip:45590",
    "active": "true",
    "opid": 63869351,
    "secs_running": 36,
    "microsecs_running": 36136211,
    "op": "query",
    "ns": "cuda.call_history",
    "query": {
        "find": "call_history",
        "filter": {
            "is_removed": false,
            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam": true,
            "trk.0.direction": "ingress",
            "date": {
                "$gt": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
                "$lt": "4001-01-01 00:00:00"
            },
            "trk.0.extra_data.status": {
                "$in": [
                    "success",
                    "p_received"
                ]
            },
            "trk.0.type": "clk",
            "owner_id": "00000000000040008000000000003828"
        },
        "sort": {
            "date": -1
        },
        "limit": 31
    },
    "numYields": 6600,
    "locks": {},
    "waitingForLock": "false",
    "lockStats": {
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 13200
            }
        },
        "MMAPV1Journal": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 6611
            },
            "acquireWaitCount": {
                "r": 9
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros": {
                "r": 50854
            }
        },
        "Database": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 6600
            }
        },
        "Collection": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "R": 6600
            },
            "acquireWaitCount": {
                "R": 11
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros": {
                "R": 163707
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output of `db.stats()`:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
    "db" : "cuda",
    "collections" : 5,
    "views" : 0,
    "objects" : 55009248,
    "avgObjSize" : 2018.6135346551184,
    "dataSize" : 111042412544,
    "storageSize" : 113055362336,
    "numExtents" : 100,
    "indexes" : 7,
    "indexSize" : 14223460160,
    "fileSize" : 133012914176,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

`mongostat` displays the below result, I think fault number is high:

```
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize   res faults qrw arw net_in net_out conn set repl                time
     5    93      4     *0       0    64|0       0         282G 9.11G     26 0|0 0|0  64.3k    187k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:14.476
    *0   107     *0      1       0    58|0       0         282G 9.14G      4 0|0 0|0  51.5k    247k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:15.475
     2    88      5     *0       0    70|0       0         282G 9.04G     26 0|0 0|0  61.5k    245k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:16.476
     3    98      2     *0       0    71|0       0         282G 9.12G      6 0|0 0|0  59.6k    274k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:17.474
     1   105     *0      1       0    82|0       0         282G 9.10G     14 0|0 0|0  63.4k    254k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:18.476
     1    88      2     *0       0    68|0       0         282G 9.12G     75 0|0 0|0  49.9k    194k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:19.476
     5   120      4     *0       0    78|0       0         282G 9.11G      5 0|0 0|0  75.7k    548k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:20.476
     3    89     *0      4       0    64|0       0         282G 9.14G     19 0|0 0|0  55.3k   1.59m  483 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:21.476
    *0    81     *0     *0       0    62|0       0         282G 9.17G      0 0|0 0|0  46.9k    265k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:22.476
     6   105      3     *0       0    67|0       0         282G 9.15G     49 0|0 0|0  61.8k    240k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:23.475
```

**And under load we have high page faults:**

```
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize   res faults  qrw  arw net_in net_out conn set repl                time
     1    96     *0     *0       0    70|0       0         282G 10.9G    597  0|0  2|0  59.1k   1.06m  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:45.061
     1   103      3     *0       0    79|0       0         282G 10.9G    715  0|0  0|0  66.4k    176k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:46.060
     2   102     *0     *0       0    72|0       0         282G 10.9G    718  0|0  2|0  59.6k    154k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:47.060
     2   104      2      1       0    83|0       0         282G 11.0G    692  0|0  3|0  68.7k    154k  483 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:48.061
     2   103      2     *0       0    86|0       0         282G 11.0G    743  0|0  1|0  64.2k    154k  482 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:49.059
    *0   116      2     *0       0    95|0       0         282G 11.0G    715  0|0  2|0  68.5k    237k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:50.060
     1   112      6      1       0    78|0       0         282G 11.0G    595  0|0  2|0  74.3k    231k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:51.061
     2   137      5      1       0    83|0       0         282G 11.0G    733  0|0  3|0  81.6k    301k  480 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:52.060
     3   157      5      1       0    92|0       0         282G 11.0G    697  0|0  3|0  89.5k    183k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:53.059
     4   102      3     *0       0    73|0       0         282G 10.9G    599  0|0  1|0  67.1k    154k  480 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:54.060
```

We have about 15GB of free memory that part of it is used by `MongoDB` for cache!

On peak we reach 400 OPS, and 500 connections per seconds. Is there anything I could do to **improve the performance?**

Comment: What kind of cluster/set do you have?

Comment: @Zlatko it is a standalone mongoDB server. We have enabled `replication` just in order to capture collection updates in our scripts.

Comment: @Zlatko could you take a look at the edited part (mongostat)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add nothing useful. To me it simply looks you need a better host. And a replica set, at least. That you should take regardless. MongoDB will eat your data otherwise.